# Getting file from GCP bucket in Katib

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow, kubeflow-katib

I am setting up a YAML template for Katib, which will follow the same optimizing script and process but with different inputs, so I would like to get the file from a bucket given the path to the file itself.

I used it on a different pipeline with Argo Workflows and it was added like this inside the **container** parameter:

```
inputs:
    artifacts:
      - gcs:
          bucket: 'INPUT_BUCKET_NAME'
          key: 'FILE_NAME'
        name: my-art
        path: /my-artifact
    parameters:
      - name: Bucket
        value: 'INPUT_BUCKET_NAME'
      - name: File
        value: 'FILE_NAME'
```

But the approach seems different in Katib with Kubeflow